# Specific Feature Copying

Tags: arcpy, spatial-database, walk

I'm trying to write a script to copy multiple feature classes from two different databases into a single database, but I want to be able to specity what features I actually want. I know I need to use da.Walk to get through the first files but am stumped on how I can actually do this. Any thoughts?

here is what i have so far.

```
`import arcpy, os, string 

workspace= ""

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for filename in filenames:`
```

Comment: If you create a layer with a whereclause then use a tool like append then only the specified features will be copied. What part are you having trouble with? Can you post the code you've got please.

Comment: please edit your question and insert your code with formatting. It is very important for python to be formatted correctly (use the {} button)

Comment: Edited the code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example of how you can use a list comprehension, `fnmatch` and `walk` to get at specific files within multiple geodatabases.  In this example I specified that I wanted all polygon feature classes with a "poly" prefix.  As an added bonus, list comprehensions are blazingly fast compared to stand alone nested `for` loops.

```
import arcpy, os, fnmatch

path = r'C:\gdrive\temp\test'

myfiles = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in arcpy.da.Walk(path, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files, 'poly*')]

# Copy the files over starting here...
```

---

[image]

Comment: That's very similar to os.walk() - another handy one to know.  Is fnmatch a standard library, I've not seen that one before? Is the extra ']' supposed to be there on the end of *for f in fnmatch.filter(files, 'poly*')]*?

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson Yes, `fnmatch` is a standard library with Python 2.7.  The `]` is supposed to be there--it is part of the list comprehension.

Comment: I see it now, it's on 3 lines. Thanks @Aaron.